# Stop receiving an event for some time in socket io

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, eventemitter

I am flooded with many events simultaneously in my socket io client. There are suppose any two events `eventA and eventB`, of which `eventB` is of use only after `eventA` occurs. So till then I want to ignore that event.

How can I achieve this scenario using `socket.io` in nodejs?

Comment: can't you just return; in the listening of eventB if eventA is not there yet?

Comment: I was looking for something supported by `socket.io` package.

Comment: you could find some fancy method, but sometimes it's best to go the easy way, unless you have a reason not to.

Comment: Nodejs is synchronous (its I/O is asynchronous). So when I enter an event's callback, the other events get queued which means `eventA` might have occurred but might have been queued due to prior firings of `eventB`. So to avoid this delay, I want that there should be some way to turn that event off so that callback is not entered.

Comment: The problem I am facing is, if events get fired this way : `eventB, eventB, eventB, eventB, eventB, eventB, eventA`. All these events occur in infinitesimal time difference.

Comment: can't you unlisten eventB and listen to it again when eventA gets through?

Comment: That sounds good. I would like to know if there is some time tradeoff in binding and unbinding events.

Comment: well, because the bind and unbinding is happening in the same thread as the process of queued events, loosing a few milliseconds wouldn't harm the logic of your app. but the concern you have for time is really interesting, wonder if you can optimizes the rate of events being sent to server.